# Syntax Highlighting CSS in PHP

Tags: php, css, syntax-highlighting

I have a CSS parser thats printing out stylesheet to the browser like so:

```
$cssParser->parse( 'style.css' );
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $cssParser ); echo '</pre>';
```

Can I 'syntax highlight' the output CSS somehow?

Thanks

Comment: What does `$cssParser->parse('style.css')` do? Break the CSS into some kind of mapping of names to values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to code-highlight something using PHP, getting some HTML code as output, [GeSHi - Generic Syntax Highlighter](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) is a nice solution *(used by many software, should I add)*, that supports lots of languages -- and CSS seems to be one of those.

If you want to try it without integrating it into your application first, there is a [demo page](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/demo.php) available, btw.

Answer (score 4):

[Hyperlight](http://code.google.com/p/hyperlight/)? (download from svn at http://code.google.com/p/hyperlight/source/browse/trunk/)

[PHP syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230270/php-syntax-highlighting)?

Comment: Tried, but there's nothing in the download section.

Comment: Damn, I really need to produce a release for the project. :-(