# Source code indentation and highlighting on server side?

Tags: java, php, jsp, server-side

I  need to do source code formatting (similar to what Stack Overflow does), but on the server side. What options do I have? My serverside language could be PHP or JSP. 
Does google have a server version of syntaxhighlighter?

Comment: I suggest you refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230270/php-syntax-highlighting) for a PHP solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP syntax highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230270/php-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

Try enscript. I use it to for syntax-highlighted printouts, but it also generates html, rtf and even ANSI codes.

```
$ enscript -w html -o program.html program.c
```

it's a standalone utility, so you can use it from any language.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/). With over 150 languages supported is my favourite syntax highlight solution for PHP :)