# Best server side syntax highlighting solution (in PHP)

Tags: php, html, parsing, string, syntax-highlighting

Do you guys know a syntax highlighter capable of highlighting mixed PHP+HTML+CSS+JS code?

like:

```
<?php
 echo 'foo';
?>
<div> foo </div>
<style type="text/css">
  .foo {color: #3d3;}
</style>
```

I only know [GeShi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) so far. It's pretty cool, but it only supports one language at a time.

Comment: Are you looking for an IDE or you want to highlight code in a web page you are rendering?

Comment: in a web site, highlight before output

Comment: @Alexndra, great, thanks for the clarification. I guess I didn't read your question carefully.

Comment: i know this doesn't do fully what you want, but there is something to be said for the php highlight_string() function.

Comment: also, most people use client side javascript solutions for this, because highlighting string during output each time a page is requested is very taxing on a server, and highlighting on input makes future editing a pain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP syntax highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230270/php-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not PHP, but [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) is awesome. And it is faster than GeShi, even used in PHP with the `system()`function.

Comment: There is an bridge for Pygments in PHP [PHPygments](https://github.com/capy/PHPygments) and is well documented

Comment: That's good to know, it did not exist two years ago when I wrote this answer.